# Converting Coordinates and Dimensions to Box2D world

Tags: box2d, libgdx, andengine

I have a level editor that uses a coordinate system based in AndEngine.

Which uses anchor center point to the left lower corner of sprites, and 0,0 is top left corner.

The problem is i am using the physics in my Libgdx project and i use the width, height, x and y coordinates for Box2D Polygon shapes from the xml generated from my level editor.

When i use the width, height, x and y, the bodies are placed at positions i don't want them to be placed at and way to big.

With that being said, how do i make the coordinates, and dimensions show up in the same way as created in the editor?

Comment: Do you have a pixels to meters value established and in use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the differences between the **Level Editor** coordinates and **Libgdx** coordinates. And make a loader for that level editor with them. (You can even share your loader in the forums if good hearted :p)

For example: One difference that you mention is that sprite position in the editor is **top-left** corner, libgdx is **bottom-left** corner. In your loader you can place the sprites 1 spriteheight below, and that would be enough for that difference :)